# Is an Implicit Member Expression the preferred way to write in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a benefit to using implicit member expression?

From the [Swift Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID394):

> An implicit member expression is an abbreviated way to access a member of a type, such as an enumeration case or a type method, in a context where type inference can determine the implied type.

An example of this would be:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingMiddle // NSLineBreakMode
```

or

```
let button = UIButton()
button.backgroundColor = .brownColor() // UIColor()
```

Is it considered redundant to use the longer version and is there any sort of performance benefit to using Implicit Member Expression? Or is it purely style / personal preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no performance benefit to either style.

Good style is probably to use the implicit syntax where you can, unless  omitting the type name makes the code confusing.

Comment: I find cod confusing and fishy when I'm programming. :)

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense.